# Suppress messages from the IPython Notebook engine

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I usually start the IPython Notebook engine and put it in the background. But whenever users open/close notebooks or timeouts happen, I see the background spitting out messages on the terminal from where I started it - which is kind of annoying.

Is there a way to suppress those and make the engine stay silently in the background? I suspect this might be a simple switch at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the simple piping of the output to [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device#Usage), which does the trick:

```
alias start_ipy='cd /path_notebook_folder; ipython notebook --profile=nbserver --no-browser --pylab inline --port=443 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &'
```