# Stop Jupyter Notebook from printing warnings / status updates to the terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I love [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter). However, it prints many, many updates to the terminal it was started from. For example, every time a file is saved manually or automatically, a line is printed. It makes the terminal virtually useless.

How do I stop it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992278/supress-messages-from-ipython-notebook-engine?rq=1

Comment: I tried: 'ipython notebook --no-browser --port=443 2> /dev/null > /dev/null' but it did not work. In fact, no notebook is opened. Even tried it without the '--no-browser' option.

Comment: Start with `jupyter notebook >/dev/null 2>&1` and read up on dev/null redirection

Comment: ... that said, I suggest you not try to suppress the output messages. They don't render the terminal unusable, just one window of the terminal -- simply open other windows for other work.  Meanwhile the messages that are output from the Jupyter notebook are potentially important and are worth at least glancing at in case of warnings or errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide all warnings in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython)

Answer (score 68):

```
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

This would help you get rid of normal warnings.

Comment: This is not the answer!

Answer (score 14):

You can easily disable the warnings **permanently** by just adding the following code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

to the following file:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/disable-warnings.py
```

Comment: This works great, as I don't need to embed the code into every and each script or session.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following on the top of your code,

```
import warnings;
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

3 lines ...

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

Comment: That is more than the other answers. *Why* is that necessary? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71857703/edit), not here in comments (***************** ***without*** ***************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).