# How to disable warning in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I want to remove the red warnings.

None of the answers mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572118/stop-jupyter-notebook-from-printing-warnings-status-updates-to-terminal) have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example (`pd.read_table` where the warnings are all regarding an incorrect number of columns in the data file) you can add `warn_bad_lines=False` to the call:

```py
pd.read_table(filename, header=0, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
```