# Disabling warning in jupyter notebook does not work for numpy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, warnings

I use the nightly build of scikit and when I fit estimators I get this warning which is caused py the yeo.yohnson power transformer:

```
/home/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/MASTER/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:235: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  x = um.multiply(x, x, out=x)
```

Versions:
Numpy 1.22.3
Scikit 1.2.dev0

I can not really debug it, because I do not know where excatly the overflow happens so I tried to filter or turn off the warning with all these statements seperately. I use Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

1.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

2. `warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')`
3. `np.seterr(all="ignore")`

I tried a few others but nothing worked. HOWEVER except for numpy all other warnings are successfully surpressed. Why is this happening? It seems that numpy is a special case where this does not work?

Comment: Tried [these three lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857703/8508004) in your notebook? Tried `%%capture --no-display` [here](https://softhints.com/turn-off-warnings-jupyterlab-jupyter-notebook/). Unfortunately you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example so that others could test the suggestions. There's fancier and finer 'captures' available that can be used to suppress unwanted output. For example, if numpy is using a C extension there then maybe [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) would be needed.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to threads and processes. How does warning behave if the error is produced in another thread or process?

Comment: Or even more how does it behave if the additional thread produces the warning

Comment: Are you using PowerTransformer? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/23319